# Why is &> preferred over >&?

Tags: bash

The bash manpage says:

> **Redirecting Standard Output and Standard Error**
>   Bash allows both the standard output (file descriptor 1) and the 
>   standard error output (file descriptor 2) to be redirected to the
>   file whose name is the expansion of word with this construct.
>
> There are two formats for redirecting standard output and standard error:
>
> ```
> &>word
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> >&word
> ```
>
> Of the two forms, the first is preferred.  This is semantically equivalent to
>
> ```
> >word 2>&1
> ```

Why is the first form preferred?

Comment: I want an explanation of the bash semantics, not the noun's ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author is saying that `&>word` and `>&word` are both the same, and both equivalent to `>word 2>&1`. In addition, the first form is preferred.

The immediately following text [in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) says why:

> When using the second form, word may not expand to a number or ‘-’. If
>   it does, other redirection operators apply (see Duplicating File
>   Descriptors below) for compatibility reasons.

Comment: "no reason is given for it". This is what I want to know. :-)

Comment: Indeed. Because `[n]>&word` is the syntax for fd duplication when `word` is a number or `-` and so using `>&word` where `word` is a file is a confusing syntactic collision. I think the better question is why is this even allowed.

Comment: Additionally the only reason the the `>&file` syntax even works is even legal, as far as I can see, is because the [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_06) says "If `word` evaluates to something else, the behavior is unspecified."

Comment: I'm still learning a lot of these strange things, but it seems like one could write a book on "Why is this even allowed in Bash."

Comment: Totally makes sense but I couldn't figure it. That explanation is missing from bash 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu).